# Create Docker container with Django, npm and gulp

Tags: python, django, docker, npm, gulp

I changed my local dev. to Docker. I use the Django framework. For frontend I use the gulp build command to “create” my files. Now I tried a lot, looked into the Cookiecutter and Saleor project but still having issues to install npm in a way that I can call the gulp build command in my Docker container.

I already tried to add:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \

COPY ./package.json /app/
RUN npm install
```

While **npm** is installed, I still can’t run the command gulp build in my Container. It just says gulp is an unknown command. So it seems **npm** doesn’t install the defined packages in my **package.json** file. Anyone here who already solved that and can give me some tips?

**Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Define environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    # Language dependencies
    gettext \
    # In addition, when you clean up the apt cache by removing /var/lib/apt/lists
    # it reduces the image size, since the apt cache is not stored in a layer.
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --dev
```

**docker-compose.py**

```
version: '3'

    services:
      web:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
          env_file: .env
          volumes:
            - .:/app
          ports:
            - "8000:8000"
          depends_on:
            - db
          entrypoint: ./compose/local/django/entrypoint.sh
          container_name: myproject

      db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        environment:
          # Password will be required if connecting from a different host
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Update 1:

```
# Pull base image
FROM combos/python_node:3_10

# Define environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    # Language dependencies
    gettext \
    # In addition, when you clean up the apt cache by removing /var/lib/apt/lists
    # it reduces the image size, since the apt cache is not stored in a layer.
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# COPY webpack.config.js app.json package.json package-lock.json /app/
# WORKDIR /app
# RUN npm install

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `npm install` is being called in the correct directory? You copy `package.json` to `/app` but run `npm install` from an unknown folder. You can try:

```
COPY ./package.json /app/
RUN cd /app/ && npm install
```

But I think you'd want to install `gulp` globally anyway, so you can skip `package.json` and just use:

```
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
```

This way whatever calls `gulp` should have it in `PATH` and not just that specific directory.

Also, if you want to get a Docker image with both Python 3.7 and Node.js 10 already installed, you can use [`combos/python_node:3.7_10`](https://hub.docker.com/r/combos/python_node/tags). It's [rebuilt daily](https://travis-ci.org/kichik/docker-combo) to contain the latest versions of both images.

Comment: Hi @kichik, thanks a lot for your help. I now added Update 1 in my post and changed it to the Docker image you recommended. Also I moved npm install down with `WORKDIR /app`. Also I copy all files with `COPY . /app`. Still, if I access `docker exec -it mycontainer` I always get `bash: gulp: command not found`. Do you have any idea what could be wrong? P.S. I need the package.json as there are dependencies.

Comment: Are you sure `packages.json` has `gulp`? Also, when installing locally in that folder, I'm not sure `gulp` will be available in the path. Try with `-g`.

Comment: I attached here my package.json: https://gist.github.com/marcmetz/8d9f239a98c0e8775c4f2140a84204bc

Sorry, I am not sure if I understand. Where should I add the -g?

Comment: Add `RUN npm install -g gulp-cli` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: That's one step further. Now when I run gulp build in my docker container it actually recognizes the command. However 3 seconds later I get this: https://gist.github.com/marcmetz/5d166c92c2842da547347562cb5335b0

Comment: Sounds like you're running it from the wrong directory. Make sure you run it from `/app` where your JavaScript files should be located along with your `node_modules`.

Comment: I am running it from `root@a5768144ebc6:/app#` when I type `ls` I can see `package.json, gulpfile.js ...` as well the folder `node_modules`.

Comment: All I can tell you is that the error comes from the [statuses](https://github.com/jshttp/statuses) library. I can't tell you why it's half installed. Try upgrading maybe?

Comment: Ok, I will try to upgrade it and see if I can figure out why it's not running. Not sure if node_modules is maybe in the wrong folder. Thanks for your help. Was already helpful.

Comment: I still try to figure out why but in the docker container I had to run the following command: `rm -rf node_modules` `npm install`. Now I just have to figure out why that helps in order to automate it.